# Inverse_of doesn't work when preloading, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

Given the following:

```
class Ns::Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many    :products, foreign_key: :ns_order_id , inverse_of: :collection
end


class NS::Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to  :collection, foreign_key: :ns_order_id, inverse_of: :products
end
```

Can someone explain why the following returns true:

```
a = Ns::Collection.first
b = a.products[0]
a.code == b.collection.code
a.code = 'Something'
a.code == b.collection.code
```

But when i try to preload, it returns false:

```
a = Ns::Collection.includes(:products).first
b = a.products[0]
a.code == b.collection.code
a.code = 'Something'
a.code == b.collection.code
```

Comment: Look at RailsGuide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html, has_many should not have foreign_key: :ns_order_id. This is a problem. Check also SQL produced in log in this situations.

Comment: I don't see anything about "has_many should not have foreign_key". Also, my association works correctly, my particular case needs a custom foreign key, unfortunately. Finally, this is the reason I put the inverse_of in the first place.